# Pass through referrer to a link

Tags: javascript, http, hyperlink, http-headers, referrer

I have website `domain1.com` and `domain2.com`. Suppose a user gets to `domain1.com` from `theoriginalreferrer.com` then clicks on a link to `domain2.com`.

In this scenario, I'd like to pass on the referrer of `domain1.com` to `domain2.com` - ie I would like the `document.referrer` of `domain2.com` to show `theoriginalreferrer.com` instead of `domain1.com`. Is this possible?

I realize one option is to simply add a query string to the link to domain2 to be `domain2.com?referrer=...` and inject the existing `document.referrer` from domain1. This is not ideal for my situation and I'd prefer to be able to somehow directly affect domain2's `document.referrer` when a link is clicked on `domain1.com`

Comment: You could save the referrer and use it in `domain2.com`. Have you tried anything? Your goal seems a bit arbitrary. Why `google.com`? How many levels of referrers should this cover? Can you generalize your requirement a bit?

Comment: @Xufox Happy to clarify but you didn't have to downvote the question... All I am asking is whether its possible to overwrite what the referrer is when a link is clicked on a site.

google.com is arbitrary. And sure I could save the referrer on domain1 and pass it as a query param to domain2 but that is not what I was asking...

Comment: Yes, I did have to downvote, because no attempt was shown and the queston was unclear.

Comment: @Xufox Hope I have clarified enough now. Would you please remove the downvote? If not please indicate what additional info you think would be necessary.

Comment: Yep, it’s fine now.

Comment: Are you trying to just see the original referrer in document.referrer, or are you trying to alter the Referer HTTP header in the request to the second site?  If the latter, I don't think you can alter Referer headers in script, so you would have only 2 options.  1 using querystring, second using jscript to handle all hyperlink clicks and convert them to posts with the referrer as form data.  Probably neither is a good option.

Comment: @Adrien got it - thanks!